# Android ListView selection background

Tags: android, listview

Okay I'm going absolutely nuts with this. I have a ListView in mode singleChoice, when I click on it I set it to selected. And I set the background to a drawable with a selector (and I tried many states that could correspond to a selected item). However when I select it the background doesn't change and I dont get why. I visited dozens of forums for this but couldn't get an answer. Here's my code:

The ListView in my activity:

```
<com.gaetanl.aspa.ui.component.ExtensibleListView
    android:id="@+id/payment_billing_address_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/item_selectable"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"></com.gaetanl.aspa.ui.component.ExtensibleListView>
```

Its class:

```
public class ExtensibleListView extends ListView {
    public ExtensibleListView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ExtensibleListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.listViewStyle);
    }

    public ExtensibleListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(this, "item " + position + " selected = " + view.isSelected());
                view.setSelected(true);
                Log.d(this, "selected = " + view.isSelected());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    }
}
```

The selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_activated="true"
        android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <item
        android:state_active="true"
        android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want to achieve .. do you want to change the background color of the list view item that's been selected?

Comment: Yes that's it !

Comment: post your adapter class for the list view please, I might be able to hep you then.

Comment: I use a simple array adapter with the default item layout: new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the answer. I was stupidly trying to set the ListView background (see code above). What I needed to do was, when creating adapter, to select a view for the items that incorporates variation for selected items. Android has one by default: simple_list_item_single_choice.

So here's the working code:

```
myListView = ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_id));
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, myList);
myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        view.setSelected(true);
    }
});
```

And then you have it, a list view with radio buttons on the right that check themselves when you click on em.

And here's the ListView in my layout.xml:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice">
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Method I:

In your list adapter,create getter and setter methods for position.Then in getView method, compare the position as in below:

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item.xml, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();        holder.itemLayout(LinearLyout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_layout);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if(position==getPosition()){
            holder.itemLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.back_ground_color));
        }else{
            holder.itemLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.background_unselect));
        }
        return convertView;
    }
public void setPosition(int posit) {
        this.position = posit;
    }

    private int getPosition() {
        return this.position;
    }
```

Then in the activity , inside listView's onItemSelected() method: call the adapter's setPositionMethod:

```
list_view.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                mAdapter.setPosition(i);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

Just set the list selector to transparent ..that should do the job.

> Method II:

Or may be ,You need a selector like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/color_primary" >
    </item>
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@color/color_primary" >
    </item>
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawablecolor="@color/color_primary" >
    </item>
    <item android:color="@color/@color/transparent" >
    </item>

</selector>
```

then put list selector as @drawable/list_selector

But, if that doesn't work then I think you can set the background of item xml layout as

```
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
```